# How to fix log4net console output configuration

Tags: c#, log4net

I have created a Console App (.Net Framework) project for my NSelene UI automation project. Currently, I am configuring log4net. Unfortunately, I am unable to log into an output window (log4net is writing only into a file).

Test output showing next error: 
log4net:ERROR XmlHierarchyConfigurator: No appender named [DebugAppender] could be found.
log4net:ERROR Appender named [DebugAppender] not found.

I have added `[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]` into AssemblyInfo.cs file

app.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" 
type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="DebugAppender " 
type="log4net.Appender.DebugAppender">
      <immediateFlush value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c [%x] - 
%m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" 
type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="log/SBT.UI.log"/>
      <encoding value="utf-8"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Composite"/>
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}, 
%message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" 
type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c [%x] - 
%m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="DebugAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Project.cs

```
    [SetUp]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        logger.Debug("test1");
        logger.Info("test2");
        logger.Warn("test3");
        logger.Error("test4");
        logger.Fatal("test5");
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you need to change type of appender. Try `type="log4net.Appender.ManagedColoredConsoleAppender"` instead `log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender`

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work for me. I guess it's something else

Comment: I think Aleks meant instead of DebugAppender, not RollingFileAppender.

Comment: That's what I have checked

Comment: There is no appender named `DebugAppender` in your configuration, you only have one called `DebugAppender ` (mind the trailing space).